# Error compiling, PLS-00103, Encountered symbol "(", when the following was expected: ;

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle SQL Developer and i am not sure what the language is.
I have some problems when compiling. I have really scratched my head on this one and i am stuck.

The message ia get is:

> "Error(14,9): PLS-00103: Påträffade symbolen "(" då en av följande
>   förväntades:  ; Symbolen ";" ersattes med "(" för att kunna fortsätta.

and

> Error(14,54): PLS-00103: Påträffade symbolen ")" då en av följande
>   förväntades:  * & -    + / den mod rest rem  och or
>   as || multiset"

which translates to:

> "Error (14,9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:   ; Symbol ";" was substituted for "(" to continue.

and

> Error(14,54): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following  * & -    + / den mod rest rem  and or as || multiset"

The code was copied from a .txt file, and something that struck med is that there might be some illegal white character, but i can not find any.

```
create or replace FUNCTION FISKEBY_PS_CALC_PEDKAT(std_ in varchar2, mediafas_ in varchar2, fluidgrupp_ in varchar2, konstruktionstemp_ in varchar2, tryck_ in varchar2, DN_ in varchar2) return varchar2 is
BEGIN
  if (mediafas_='STABIL GAS' and fluidgrupp_='1') then
  BEGIN
if(tryck_<0.5) then RETURN 'Ingen klass';
elsif (DN_<25 and tryck_>=0.5) then RETURN 'Klass 0';
elsif (DN_<100 and DN_>=25 and tryck_*DN_<1000) then RETURN 'Klass I';
elsif((DN_<350 and DN_>=100 and tryck_<10) or (DN_<350 and DN_>=25 and tryck_*DN_<3500 and tryck_*DN_>=1000)or(DN_<100 and DN_>=25 and tryck_*DN_>1000)) then RETURN 'Klass II';
elsif(DN_>=350 or (tryck_*DN_>=3500 and DN_>=100)) then RETURN 'Klass III';
else RETURN '';
end if;
  END

  elsif (mediafas_='INSTABIL GAS' and fluidgrupp_='1') then
  BEGIN
if(tryck_<0.5) then RETURN 'Ingen klass';
elsif(DN_<25 and tryck_>=0.5) then RETURN 'Klass 0';
elsif(DN_>=25 and tryck_>=0.5) then RETURN 'Klass III';
else RETURN '';
end if;
  END

  elsif(mediafas_='STABIL GAS' and fluidgrupp_='2') then
  BEGIN
if(tryck_<0.5) then RETURN 'Ingen klass';
elsif(DN_<32 or DN_*tryck_<1000) then RETURN 'Klass 0';
elsif(DN_<100 or DN_*tryck_<3500) then RETURN 'Klass I';
elsif((DN_<250 or DN_*tryck_<5000) and konstruktionstemp_<350) then RETURN 'Klass II';
elsif((DN_>=250 or DN_*tryck_>=5000) or (DN_<250 or DN_*tryck_<5000) and konstruktionstemp_>=350) then RETURN 'Klass III';
else RETURN '';
end if;
  END

  elsif(mediafas_='VÄTSKA' and fluidgrupp_='1') then
 BEGIN
if(tryck_<0.5) then RETURN 'Ingen klass';
elsif(DN_<25 or DN_*tryck_<2000) then RETURN 'Klass 0';
elsif(DN_>=25 and DN_*tryck_>=2000 and tryck_>=0.5 and tryck_<10) then RETURN 'Klass I';
elsif(DN_>=25 and DN_*tryck_>=2000 and tryck_>=10 and tryck_<500) then RETURN 'Klass II';
elsif(DN_>=25 and DN_*tryck_>=2000 and tryck_>=500) then RETURN 'Klass III';
else RETURN '';
end if;
  END

 elsif(mediafas_='VÄTSKA' and fluidgrupp_='2') then
  BEGIN
if(tryck_<0.5) then RETURN 'Ingen klass';
elsif(DN_<200 or DN_*tryck_<5000 or tryck_<10) then RETURN 'Klass 0';
elsif(DN_>=200 and DN_*tryck_>=5000 and tryck_>10 and tryck_<500) then RETURN 'Klass I';
elsif(DN_>=200 and DN_*tryck_>=5000  and tryck_>=500) then RETURN 'Klass II';
else RETURN '';
end if;
  END

else RETURN '';
end if;

END FISKEBY_PS_CALC_PEDKAT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing some semicolons after you END's. I also put spaces after your elsif's. Compiled clean.

```
create or replace FUNCTION FISKEBY_PS_CALC_PEDKAT(std_ in varchar2, mediafas_ in varchar2, fluidgrupp_ in varchar2, konstruktionstemp_ in varchar2, tryck_ in varchar2, DN_ in varchar2) return varchar2 is
BEGIN
  if (mediafas_='STABIL GAS' and fluidgrupp_='1') then
  BEGIN
if(tryck_<0.5) then RETURN 'Ingen klass';
elsif (DN_<25 and tryck_>=0.5) then RETURN 'Klass 0';
elsif (DN_<100 and DN_>=25 and tryck_*DN_<1000) then RETURN 'Klass I';
elsif((DN_<350 and DN_>=100 and tryck_<10) or (DN_<350 and DN_>=25 and tryck_*DN_<3500 and tryck_*DN_>=1000)or(DN_<100 and DN_>=25 and tryck_*DN_>1000)) then RETURN 'Klass II';
elsif(DN_>=350 or (tryck_*DN_>=3500 and DN_>=100)) then RETURN 'Klass III';
else RETURN '';
end if;
  END;

  elsif (mediafas_='INSTABIL GAS' and fluidgrupp_='1') then
  BEGIN
if(tryck_<0.5) then RETURN 'Ingen klass';
elsif(DN_<25 and tryck_>=0.5) then RETURN 'Klass 0';
elsif(DN_>=25 and tryck_>=0.5) then RETURN 'Klass III';
else RETURN '';
end if;
  END;

  elsif (mediafas_='STABIL GAS' and fluidgrupp_='2') then
  BEGIN
if(tryck_<0.5) then RETURN 'Ingen klass';
elsif(DN_<32 or DN_*tryck_<1000) then RETURN 'Klass 0';
elsif(DN_<100 or DN_*tryck_<3500) then RETURN 'Klass I';
elsif((DN_<250 or DN_*tryck_<5000) and konstruktionstemp_<350) then RETURN 'Klass II';
elsif((DN_>=250 or DN_*tryck_>=5000) or (DN_<250 or DN_*tryck_<5000) and konstruktionstemp_>=350) then RETURN 'Klass III';
else RETURN '';
end if;
  END;

  elsif (mediafas_='VDTSKA' and fluidgrupp_='1') then
 BEGIN
if(tryck_<0.5) then RETURN 'Ingen klass';
elsif(DN_<25 or DN_*tryck_<2000) then RETURN 'Klass 0';
elsif(DN_>=25 and DN_*tryck_>=2000 and tryck_>=0.5 and tryck_<10) then RETURN 'Klass I';
elsif(DN_>=25 and DN_*tryck_>=2000 and tryck_>=10 and tryck_<500) then RETURN 'Klass II';
elsif(DN_>=25 and DN_*tryck_>=2000 and tryck_>=500) then RETURN 'Klass III';
else RETURN '';
end if;
  END;

 elsif (mediafas_='VDTSKA' and fluidgrupp_='2') then
  BEGIN
if(tryck_<0.5) then RETURN 'Ingen klass';
elsif(DN_<200 or DN_*tryck_<5000 or tryck_<10) then RETURN 'Klass 0';
elsif(DN_>=200 and DN_*tryck_>=5000 and tryck_>10 and tryck_<500) then RETURN 'Klass I';
elsif(DN_>=200 and DN_*tryck_>=5000  and tryck_>=500) then RETURN 'Klass II';
else RETURN '';
end if;
  END;

else RETURN '';
end if;

END FISKEBY_PS_CALC_PEDKAT;
```